# How can i fix Listview and Mysql repeats?

Tags: c#, mysql, listview

I have created a listview that includes my database, but everytime i press ''List It'', it repeats itself in lisview. Do you know how to solve it?
And I fill textboxes to submit informations, it isnt seen in listview.
There's the code for Submit;

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        keko.Open();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into calisanlist(Adı,Soyadı,Yevmiye) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')", keko);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        keko.Close();
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
```

There's the code for List It;

```
 private void verilerigoruntule()
    {


        keko.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from calisanlist", keko);
        MySqlDataReader gr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(gr.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem ekle = new ListViewItem();
            ekle.Text = gr["Adı"].ToString();
            ekle.SubItems.Add(gr["Soyadı"].ToString());
            ekle.SubItems.Add(gr["Yevmiye"].ToString());
            ekle.SubItems.Add(gr["Gun"].ToString());
            ekle.SubItems.Add(gr["Maaş"].ToString());

            listView1.Items.Add(ekle);



        }
        keko.Close();

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        verilerigoruntule();

    }
```

Comment: Anyone help me?

Comment: Try clearing your listview before adding items again

Comment: then, nothing seems in listview when i press submit

Comment: Like listView1.Items.Clear()  before you actually start adding items yet again. This could even be before you call verilerigoruntule()  in the button2_click event